# HTML Map Clickable

Tags: html, css, maps

So I have been searching on google for over half an hour now trying to find an easy html clickable map without any JS if possible but I just can't find one that suits my needs. I just want it to be a map with all of the countries in a container or something so I can make a quiz for myself (I want my OWN one). I just thought it would be fun to try to make a quiz for myself but I just need a world map template.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to suggest, sometimes the thing you want isn't already done for you and free of charge.. that's why jobs exist... What exactly are you after? Are you tired of searching google and want someone else to search for you? Or do you want someone to make one for you? Or are you asking if _maybe_ someone might know of one?

Comment: I am asking if anyone know of one like Maxouhell did(didn't really suit me though).

Answer (score 0):

I think MapBox Studio can help you.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/

It's easy to use, i don't need to explain a lot :)

I hope this is help you !